# eric6 can't compile in Python form (could not start pyuic5.exe)

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt5

I am trying to create a GUI using `eric6` for a Python script I coded recently, however when I right click in eric6 on the new `*.ui` file I create and I try to compile it (choosing '`Compile Form`'), the following error is displayed - `could not start puyic5.exe`:

[image: error message]

I have tried the (very few) online solutions but without any luck (for example, checking that in the `pyuic5.bat` file, the mentioned directory is without any space, and also tried to re-install Qt5). Furthermore, even though both Python and PyQt are correctly installed, `pyuic5.exe` is missing in the directory specified in the error. Also, everything seems setup ok in the PATH in the system environmental variables.

Versions info:

```
Python 3.4.5
Qt 5.4.1
PyQt 5.4.1
eric6 17.06
```

EDIT: if it can help debugging my issue, I would like to add that if I open a command prompt and I invoke `pyuic5 mainform.ui -o mainform.py` it works without problems. Instead, in eric6, such error message is generated.
Thank you in advance for any precious help and guidance you may offer !

Sincerely,

Paolo

Answer (score 0):

Solved downgrading to an older version of eric6 (precisely to v 17.04.1). Thought it might be useful to share in case somebody encounters the same problem.